# how to scroll page to the middle on focus of input field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I trying to scroll the page up or down anytime someone tabs through input fields in a form. I want that the currently focused input element will be centered vertically at the middle of the page as a user tabs through. I wrote a directive for this but it doesn't work like i expect it to.

```
angular
     .module('app')
     .directive('formScroll', formScroll);

function formScroll($window) {

        function link(scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('focus', function() {
                var offset,
                    elOffset = elem.offset().top,
                    elHeight = elem.height(),
                    windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;

                offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight - elHeight) / 2);

                $window.scrollTo(0, offset);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate *Doesn't work like I expect* means?

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'World';
 });

app.directive('formScroll', formScroll);
    function formScroll($window) {
       return {
         link: function(scope, elem) {
                elem.bind('focus', function() {
                  var offset,
                 elOffset = elem.prop('offsetTop'), //.offset().top,
                 elHeight = elem.prop('height'), //elem.height(),
                 windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;
                 offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight - elHeight) / 2);
                 $window.scrollTo(0, offset);
               });
         }
      }
   }
```

I modified the formScroll function to return an object {link:...}, 
Also, used elem.prop(....)